Function that returns tuples composed of a Python dictionary
I'm trying to create a function that takes a list of tokenized words for a review, and a label and returns a list of tuples composed of a Python dictionary and the label associated.
You can see what I mean more clearly by what the output is supposed to look like below.
Here's the code that I have:
def featureExtraction(clean_tokenized, label):
    features = []
    for line in clean_tokenized:
        for word in line:
            d = dict({word: True})
            d1 = (d, label)
            tup.append(d1)
            
    return features

Example Input:
[['hate', 'movie'], 
['acting', 'terrible']]

Expected output:
[
  ({'hate': True, 'movie': True}, 'neg')
  ({'acting': True, 'terrible': True}, 'neg')      
]

This is what my code is producing:
[({'hate': True}, 'pos'), ({'movie': True}, 'pos'), ({'acting': True}, 'pos'), ({'terrible': True}, 'pos')]

I would love some assistance with this.

d = dict({word: True}) Your expected output is a dict with two items, and yet this code clearly makes a dict with only one item...

You're creating a separate dictionary for each word in line, not putting them in the same tuple.
You can use the dict.fromkeys() function to create a dictionary whose keys come from a list and all have the same values.
def featureExtraction(clean_tokenized, label):
    return [(dict.fromkeys(tokens, True), label) for tokens in clean_tokenized]

